# Select rows with logical TRUE using sqldf

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators, sqldf

I am using this:

```
NewDf <- sqldf("select * from OldDf where Test = 'TRUE'")
```

but I get zero rows in *NewDf*. There are definitely rows with *TRUE* in *OldDf* (*Test* column is logical with values: *TRUE* and *FALSE*).

Any ideas?

**P.S.:** This works:

```
NewDf  <- subset(OldDf, Test != 'FALSE')
```

Comment: Could you provide output of `dput(head(OldDf))`? So we can test?

Comment: sorry that would be hard as the data is large and confidential )-:

Comment: can I cast to a text?

Comment: Make a dummy example dataframe that has the same structure as the real data.

Comment: Maybe try: `sqldf("select * from OldDf where Test = 1")`

Comment: Thanks that works - but confusing for beginners like me (-: Feel free to furnish answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sqldf* stores logicals as `0` and `1` integers, see this example:

```
# dummy data
OldDf <- head(mtcars[, 1:2])
OldDf$Test <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
OldDf
#                    mpg cyl  Test
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  TRUE
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 FALSE
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  TRUE
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 FALSE
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  TRUE
# Valiant           18.1   6 FALSE

library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * from OldDf where Test = 1")
#    mpg cyl Test
# 1 21.0   6 TRUE
# 2 22.8   4 TRUE
# 3 18.7   8 TRUE

# This also works, to filter on TRUE
sqldf("select * from OldDf where Test")
#    mpg cyl Test
# 1 21.0   6 TRUE
# 2 22.8   4 TRUE
# 3 18.7   8 TRUE

# To get FALSE
sqldf("select * from OldDf where NOT Test")
#    mpg cyl  Test
# 1 21.0   6 FALSE
# 2 21.4   6 FALSE
# 3 18.1   6 FALSE
```